# shell scipt to get a file from ftp server

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which downloads a file from remote server. Though I am providing username and password still it is asking for pass in command prompt.

I have tried to hardcode the username and password but still it's asking for password in runtime

```sh
for host in $hosts
do
   ftp  $ftpop $host << ! > $TMPFILE.ftp 2>&1
      username
      password
      get $dataset $filename
!
  egrep '^421 |^425 |^426 |^450 |^451 |^452 |^530 |^531 |^550 |^551 |^552|^553 |^590 |^Not connected' $TMPFILE.ftp > /dev/null 2>&1
   rtn=$?
   if [ $rtn -eq 1 ] ; then 
      break
   fi
done
```

I expect to take the username and password and download the file.

Comment: `ftp` is not a standardized tool; different vendors' implementations can differ. Sounds likely your vendor reads the password from the TTY, not from stdin, and thus ignores the password from the heredoc.

Comment: Consider using `lftp` instead, which provides explicitly-supported mechanisms for passing a username/password pair.

Comment: lftp is not working in my script.I get error like command not found

Comment: Yes, it's a separate tool, which you need to install.

Comment: I need to do ftp only as its a existing production code

Comment: why are you still using ftp? doesnt your org forces you to switch over to sftp.

Comment: or you should be using a MFT - Managed File Transfer if a file being ftp-ed constantly

Comment: `lftp` is compatible with the standard FTP protocol; it's purely a client-side change, so what does "existing production code" have to do with it?

Comment: ...that said, if you *really* want to simulate interactive input, see `expect`.

Answer (score 0):

The typical ftp which is found in Linux honours the file `~/.netrc`, into which you can store user id, password and other useful macros (https://linux.die.net/man/5/netrc). The location of this file can be specified explicitly by setting the environment variable `NETRC`. This can be useful if you get userid and password from some other configuration file and need tor create a suitable netrc file on the fly.