# Getting error while downloading a file from ftp server

Tags: shell

The syntax is not correct .I want to add a error message when the ftp script failed.Though file is downloaded but Error is there in the last lines where i am getting successful message when the file is downloaded correctly

```
. $HOME/env
. $LIB_PATH/miip_functions.shl
dataset="'$1'"
filename=$2
file=basename $2
HOST=ftp.test
USER=test
 PASSWORD=test1

logMessage "Starting FTP download of $file."

ftp -inv $HOST <<!
user $USER $PASSWORD
get $dataset $filename
 bye
  !
  rtn=$?
   if [ $rtn -eq 1 ] ; then 
  logMessage DLOAD "Completed FTP download of $file."
 else
  logMessage ERROR "Download of $file failed."
```

I need to add message when the ftp load is failing.

Comment: Similar question 2 hours ago?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794736/shell-scipt-to-get-a-file-from-ftp-server  If the other one you could not implement the password, here you can?  Close the other one if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Minor problem: `dataset="'$1'"` is overquoted; write `dataset="$1"`.

Major problem: `ftp` doesn't set its exit status the way you'd need, so you have to check its output. E. g.:

```
logMessage "Starting FTP download of $dataset."
complete=0
(echo user $USER $PASSWORD
 echo get $dataset $filename
) | ftp -inv $HOST | while read code rest
                     do echo $code $rest
                        if [ "$code" = 226 ]; then complete=1; fi
                     done
if [ $complete -eq 1 ]; then 
  logMessage DLOAD "Completed FTP download of $dataset."
else
  logMessage ERROR "Download of $dataset failed."
fi
```

(226 is the identifying code of the `Transfer complete` message.)

> The file is downloaded but logMessage is coming as dataset failed

I notice that some shells execute the last pipeline command in a subshell, so that the `complete=1` has no effect in the parent shell. The following version, returning the `complete` value as an exit status, works even with those shells.

```
logMessage "Starting FTP download of $dataset."
complete=0
(echo user $USER $PASSWORD
 echo get $dataset $filename
) | ftp -inv $HOST | (while read code rest
                      do    echo $code $rest
                        if [ "$code" = 226 ]; then complete=1; fi
                      done && exit $complete)
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then 
  logMessage DLOAD "Completed FTP download of $dataset."
else
  logMessage ERROR "Download of $dataset failed."
fi
```

Comment: The file is downloaded but logMessage is coming as dataset failed

Comment: What is the script's output?

Comment: I meant complete is not equal to 1 i guess.

Comment: Actually the $code is not getting fetched. Do i have to delare that somewhere

Comment: What do you mean by _its actually 221_? According to [List of FTP server return codes - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) 221 is "Service closing control connection." - No, you don't have to declare `code`, it is set by the `read` command. - It could be helpful if you showed the _script's output_.

Comment: How do you know that _the $code is not getting fetched_?

Comment: Ha - I can reproduce you observation on some other system. Let's see ...